# Shopify metafield product add to cart

Tags: button, shopify, e-commerce, product, liquid

I created a custom metafild in shopify to add a suggested product to the product page.

I have added the code to my product template and I am correctly displaying the suggested product.

I want to add the add to cart button for this suggested product so that the user can add the suggested product to the cart without entering the specific page.

```
 <div class = "groups-btn">
                     {% if current_variant.available%}
                      <input data-btn-addToCart type = "submit" name = "add" class = "btn" id = "product-add-to-cart" value = "add" data-form-id = "# add-to- cart-form ">
                     {% endif%}
                     </div>
```

With this code, however, I add the main product (the one on the page) to the cart, not the suggested product.
How can I solve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding products to the cart requires you to POST the ID of the variant and a quantity. Wire up the add to cart button for your secondary product to be an Ajax call and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Can you suggest me how to do it? This is the code I have:
 <div class="recommended-products">
{% if product.metafields.my_fields.prodotto_correlato != blank %}
{% assign current_variant =  product.metafields.my_fields.prodotto_correlato.value %}
<a href="{{ current_variant.url }}">
<img src="{{ current_variant.featured_image | img_url: '100x' }}">
<div>
<p>{{ current_variant.title }}</p>
<p class="uaf__price">{{current_variant.price | money }}</p>
</div>
</a>
{% endif %}
</div>